# Troubles connecting to a Macbook remotely after some time has passed

Tags: sleep-wake, ssh

I have a Macbook (an early 2013 retina 15'', running Catalina) attached to my local network via wire with a static local IP. It is running in clam-shell mode with the lid closed and without any physical display attached.

On this Macbook there’s a Minecraft Bedrock Dedicated Server running in a Docker. I have also enabled SSH login.

Everything works fine but when I leave it and try to connect the next day I cannot do so anymore...

Neither to Minecraft server via iOS app (this uses a UDP port to connect), nor to shell via ssh (Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake), tho' ssh does work at random times.

Then when I login to the Macbook via Screen Sharing app (from another mac) all seems to be getting back to normal and both Minecraft and ssh works fine for some time.

I have disabled sleep on the Macbook also launched caffeinate, without success.

I have never had this problem on a similar set-up on a Mac mini.

Can we prevent a MacBook from going to sleep without an active display?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like MacBooks aren't designed to run headlessly.

A best workaround I could find is plugging a dongle simulating external display into the HDMI port.

[image]